# question on expected value of exponential functions

Tags: exponential-function, approximation, expected-value

When is the approximation $\mathbb{E}\left\{{e^{f(x)}}\right\} = e^{\mathbb{E}\left\{f(x)\right\}}$ tight? I mean for which function of f(x) and which conditions? there is any theorem on it?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: What distribution are you using?

Comment: i do not know what the distribution is exactly is. however, we can consider that it is Nakagami.

Comment: also, f(x) is a negative function, i.e., f(x)<0 for all x.

Answer (score 0):

If you've heard of Jensen's inequality, then using that, LHS is greater than or equal to RHS. Equality will occur iff $f(x)$ is a constant with probability 1. I'm assuming of course that the expectation on left is finite.

Comment: thanks. i know about Jensen. however, i want approximate the LHS with RHS. it is important when this would be tight?

Comment: i do not want equality.